# Why does Hexm keep installing in Android Studio

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

I try to launch my virtual box in Android Studio, it keeps telling
me:

> " intell HAXM is required to run this AVD, HAXM is not installed.
> Install Intel HAXM for better emulation performance"

But if I press ok to install it, it will still ask me again.
Its just like repeating the same steps over and over.

Comment: Try installing HAXM manually (github.com/intel/haxm/releases).

Comment: Can u guide me through the process I am a beginniner

Comment: Download haxm-windows_v7_7_0.zip from https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases, unpack it and run the installer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. Manually download the latest version of HAXM from: https://github.com/intel/haxm and install it. This works for me!